# Weird behaviour in the Questions tab when toggling between the "all questions" / "unanswered" buttons

Tags: support, bug, questions, filtering

Reproduction steps (Tested with Chrome v.51):

1. I click on the **Questions** button and redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/questions .
2. Now I can toggle between *newest / featured / frequent / votes / active*, But I just click on the **unanswered** button next to the tabs and redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered .
3. The tabs from the previous step change to *my tags / newest / votes / no answers*, but I only click on the **all questions** button next to the tabs.

Expected result:

- I should go back to questions section described in step 1 and see the filtered questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

Actual result:

- I go back to the questions section, but the list of questions is filtered by all my favorites tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+jquery+mysql+javascript+jquery-ui+html+css+angularjs Which return  no results (Because there are not questions tagged with all those tags).

This only happen if the **my tags** tab is selected when I clicked on the **all questions** button:
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags (Or just https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered if I havent selected other tab previuosly)

It's working fine when I click the **all questions** button from the *newest / votes / no answers* tabs:
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers

It look like a bug, and I haven't found other posts explaining that behaviour (Which I think is weird).

One last thing - When i'm switching between the tabs when I filter with all those tags, I see a message on the [frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+jquery+mysql+javascript+jquery-ui+html+css+angularjs?sort=newest&pageSize=15) questions tab: *You are on the Frequent tab. There are no frequently asked questions at the moment. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?* But only not on the other tabs: [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+jquery+mysql+javascript+jquery-ui+html+css+angularjs?sort=newest&pageSize=15), [votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+jquery+mysql+javascript+jquery-ui+html+css+angularjs?sort=votes&pageSize=15) and [active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+jquery+mysql+javascript+jquery-ui+html+css+angularjs?sort=active&pageSize=15). This is just to make things a little bit more consistent.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. Clicking on `unanswered` and then `all questions'  drags the favorite tags into the search terms if the `my tags` tab was selected. Definitely looks like a bug.