# Why is 'unanswered' not a tab?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

**Edit**: *I just noticed this is the standard behaviour, it doesn't happen just for tags. I still find this a bit confusing though.*

---

I search for a tag, for example `[gnuplot]` and I see this:

[image]

The first thing I notice is that the `unanswered` category is not a tab but a button.

If I click this `unanswered` button a `no answers` tab now appears and I have to click a new `all questions` button to go back to the previous state of the tabs.

[image]

This behaviour is a bit confusing to me, is this intended or some weird bug?

Comment: Note that, when the toggle is set to _Unanswered_, all tabs function differently. The _my tags_ tab is only available then, and all other tabs only show questions with no upvoted or accepted answer (including _votes_, _newest_), and the _Featured_ tab disappears.

Comment: I noticed that, and I find it rather confusing and unexpected. I don't really understand the rationale behind this behaviour.

Comment: Also note, the [new navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359643/7296893) will probably fix this. Not a clue when we can expect it, but hopefully soon. They can't remove perfectly working new nav because it's about to be released, and then not release it for over 3 months, can they?

Comment: On a related note, I was just messing with the tabs after reading this and encountered some unexpected behavior. I was about to ask a question about it, but I found that [there already was one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327648/weird-behaviour-in-the-questions-tab-when-toggling-between-the-all-questions). It seems weird that that question never got any attention. No comments or anything. Is it not a bug?

Comment: Anyway, I think the answer to your question is that it isn't a tab because it's a control for switching between different sets of tabs. I agree it isn't really intuitive, though.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just confirmed the bug you reported over a year ago.

Comment: Oh, it wasn't my report. I just found it as I was about to report it again.

Comment: Our question list views are all sorts of mess right now. They are a mix of filters and sorts and other oddities. As Shot points out, we're working on it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This changed three years or so back, when Unanswered was demoted from a top-level view listed in the header...

[image: the old old header with questions, tags, users, badges, unanswered buttons]

...to this weird little not-tab, so as to make room for Jobs and later Documentation buttons.

This was supposed to be temporary; New Nav was gonna roll out soon, and make all of this a lot less confusing and inconsistent...

The lesson here is that we should be wary any time we hear the word "temporary".

Fortunately, our crack design team is hard at work on a NEW New Nav now, so this weird button-not-a-tab unanswered link should be a temporary state of affairs.

Comment: *temporary* is just another word for 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: @rene New, new, new, new and improved nav. Coming soon(ish). ;)

Comment: @rene I always thought _temporary_ is a more polite synonym for _permanent_ ;)

Comment: @ascripter - And *permanent* is another way to say *until someone decides to change it*.

Comment: Few things are as permanent as a temporary solution.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Conversely, few things are as temporary as a permanent solution. Coincidence? You decide.

Comment: I mean this New New Nav thing is exciting and all, but I'm _really_ excited for the New New New Nav!

Comment: When a developer says it will be fixed, it will be fixed. No need to remind them every 6 months...

Comment: ahh the infamous 'temporary' which later turns into the 'well its working' which later turns into the 'I have no idea why this is here and I am afraid to change it'

Comment: *should be a temporary state of affairs* - "should be" and "temporary" after you warned us to be wary of the word "temporary"... hmmmmm... :)